# Killing all descendent processes robustly on macOS

Tags: macos, unix, posix, darwin, mach

On Linux, Pid namespaces can be used to robustly kill all descendent (including orphaned & zombie) processes – see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124148/24219) for example.

What's the closest to a "robust" way to do the same on macOS? I can't rely on process groups unfortunately as some of the descendent processes alter them.

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically (rather than at a shell)? Are you trying to do it from the process at the root of this process sub-tree or some other process?

Comment: @KenThomases Programatically, from the process at the root of the sub-tree.

Answer (score 2):

It's a gross kludge, but it might work: The first process would open a file descriptor so that, by default, all descendant processes inherit it. When it wants to kill them all, it runs `lsof` to find all processes with that file open and kills them.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work for processes which have detached themselves, but you could walk the child process tree using `proc_listchildpids()` and send signals to each PID you obtain. There are probably some timing edge cases between checking a process's children and killing it - it could spawn more processes in this time. You could perhaps suspend all processes before listing their children and killing them. Processes whose parent has died should I think be reattached to their grandparent anyway though (I may be wrong on this) so in that case, as long as you keep calling `proc_listchildpids()` after sending each round of signals you should eventually end up in a steady state. (Ideally with no child processes left. But if they get into a really bad state [due to a kernel bug], some processes may be completely unkillable.)

`proc_listchildpids()` is declared in `<libproc/libproc.h>`.